# Meteor: create user account when the client is authenticated the fist time they signin with linkedin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, meteor, linkedin-jsapi

I am running meteor.js and have globally installed npm package `node-linkedin`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin

I have registered my application with linkedin which means I have my api key, secret key and oAuth redirect urls to localhost:3000

My app currently displays the 'sign in' linkedIn button where the user grants my application access to the full profile of the user. According to linkedIn javascript API docs, the `onLinkedInAuth()` object (which runs upon successful authentication) contains the linkedin **id** of the user.

How do I create a user account, `Accounts.createUser` when the user is authenticated and store the **id** from the onLinkedInAuth() object in the user collection?

server.js

```
var Linkedin = Npm.require('node-linkedin')('api', 'secret', 'I-PUT-REDIRECT-URL-HERE');
```

How do I make the get requests using the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin (see under heading oAuth 2.0) which redirects the user to linkedins authorization dialog and subsequently retrieve the access token.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: *MY_API_KEY*
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
authorize: true
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Runs when the JavaScript framework is loaded
function onLinkedInLoad() {
IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
}
// Runs when the viewer has authenticated
function onLinkedInAuth() {
IN.API.Profile("me")
.result( function(me) {
var id = me.values[0].id;
// AJAX call to pass back id to your server
});
}
// Runs when the Profile() API call returns successfully
function displayProfiles(profiles) {
member = profiles.values[0];
document.getElementById("profiles").innerHTML = 
"<p id=\"" + member.id + "\">Hello " +  member.firstName + " " + member.lastName + "</p>";
}
</script>
</head>

<template name="parent"> //layout template
<!-- Displays a button to let the viewer authenticate -->
<script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="onLinkedInAuth"></script>
<!-- Placeholder for the greeting -->
<div id="profiles"></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a combination of https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry and https://atmospherejs.com/pauli/accounts-linkedin?  Based on the docs for http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser, you should be able to fetch the data from **options.profile**.

Comment: I'll look into this package.

Comment: I've decided to create a meteor account in the usual way sign up way and then make the API calls and save the data in the meteor account. Thanks again.